# Mechanics of UK Judicial Review: Topical for Law Site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have referred questions about the details and mechanics of UK judicial review to this site in answer(s) to travel-related questions.  Most recently here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati/64109#64109

I did NOT confirm with you that indeed such questions about how the JR process works fall within your cognizance.

Does law.stackexchange.com consider such questions on-topic?  Example:

"What do I need to do to initiate a judicial review in the UK"?

Answer (score 3):

> In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals

Judicial review would certainly be covered under

> - Legal process and procedure